# How one can create a `Map("nodes": List[Node], "edges": List[Relationship])` like the function

Tags: memgraphdb

I would be glad if someone could answer how one can create a `Map("nodes": List[Node], "edges": List[Relationship])` like the function `project(p)` does, that one can use this as a subgraph in a `CALL module.procedure(subgraph, ...)` 
Why do I need this? To chain together outputs from `path.subgraph_all` and `bridges.get`.
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
// setup graph for testing
MERGE (a:Node {id: 1}) MERGE (b:Node {id: 0}) CREATE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b);
MERGE (a:Node {id: 2}) MERGE (b:Node {id: 0}) CREATE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b);
MERGE (a:Node {id: 2}) MERGE (b:Node {id: 1}) CREATE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b);
MERGE (a:Node {id: 0}) MERGE (b:Node {id: 3}) CREATE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b);
MERGE (a:Node {id: 3}) MERGE (b:Node {id: 4}) CREATE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b);

// use project(p) - works fine
MATCH p=(:Node)-[:RELATION]-(:Node)
WITH project(p) AS subgraph
CALL bridges.get(subgraph)
YIELD node_from, node_to
RETURN node_from, node_to;

// try to get the subgraph by one node via path.subgraph_all() and then
// try to construct a Map("nodes": List[Node], "edges": List[Relationship])
// to mimic what project() does - does not work
CALL {
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n
LIMIT 1
}
CALL path.subgraph_all(n, {})
YIELD nodes, rels
CALL bridges.get({nodes: nodes, edges: rels})
YIELD node_from, node_to
RETURN node_from, node_to;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's currently no other way to pass the subgraph argument to a procedure other than output of the `project()` function. The reason for that is because the `project()` function returns the Graph type object as an output and mapping nodes and edges isn't enough for procedure to recognize the argument as a subgraph.